# Create multi-index and transpose data with pandas with columns as additional index

Tags: python, pandas

I've tried multiple things to read-in this excel file and reshape it with pandas. I've tried different functions like merge(), pivot(), melt(), reset_index() and I still can't figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
This is the current table:
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeqqb.png)

This is the desired output:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIWU.png)

Sorry for the formatting. I'm new to stackoverflow but I have done research and can't seem to figure out the answer.

I have a lot of deleted code that I tried but wasn't working here are a few examples of what I tried to do.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df.iloc[0:,0].fillna(method= 'ffill', inplace = True)
    new_cols = df.columns[2:]
    df = df.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 1":"to col"})
```

end_file_cols was a list with the columns in 'Desired' image

```
    df = df.reindex(columns = end_file_cols)
    df['Demo'] = df.index.tolist()
    df.pivot(index = 'Media', columns = new_cols.tolist())
```

This is what happens when printing df

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df.iloc[0:,0].fillna(method= 'ffill', inplace = True)
    new_cols = df.columns[2:]
    df = df.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: 1":"to col"})
    print(df)

    Media      to col  Age Group 1  Age Group 2  Age Group 3  Age Group 4
0  Plan 1  Total Cost           65            4           90           88
1  Plan 1    Net Loss           88           77           85           85
2  Plan 1       Views           60           97           76           82
3  Plan 2  Total Cost           96           92            5            0
4  Plan 2    Net Loss           89           77           51           59
5  Plan 2      Budget           42           67           49           96
6  Plan 3  Total Cost           22           78          100           10
7  Plan 3    Net Prof           59           33           72           87
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide the data so that it can be copy and pasted (not as images)

Comment: @KVEER I added some examples of what I tried but a lot of what I tried, I deleted.

Comment: @thushv89 not sure the best way to do this since it's an excel sheet. I could make a table with text but it might not be formatted properly. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `stack` and `unstack` to change `MultiIndex` between columns and rows. Simply do,

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=[0,1])
new_df = df.unstack().stack(level=0)
```

To rename the indices simply do,

```
new_df.index.rename(('Media','Demo'), inplace=True)
```

The empty values will be `np.NaN` which can be replaced with any value you want using `new_df.fillna(<value>)` (Optionally)

Comment: when I try this I get the following: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'

Comment: @FaustoRodriguez I got the same error, because I was assigning the result back to `df` while testing solutions. Did you run multiple times while replacing the same `df` variable for some reason?

Comment: Nope. Only on first re-assignment as indicated by your answer. I did the new_df = df.unstack().stack(level = 0)

Comment: My other guess is that you haven't created a `MultiIndex`. Try `df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)` before this operation.

Comment: Actually before, that can you edit your question with the result of `print(df)`?

Comment: The problem is I can't create the multi-index without adding the Age Groups to each Media Plan. Basically every Age Group is attached to a Media Plan but they dont fill every column in the "desired" output

Comment: @FaustoRodriguez, think I know why it didn't work. Try the edited answer. Essentially you need the index column to be `MultiIndex` and `read_excel()` without `index_col` argument cannot do that.